# Can the ssl certificate and remote access certificate be the same?

Tags: azure

All, I just configured SSL for my cloud service with self-signed certificate by following steps.

1. create self-signed certificate using `makecert.exe`.
2. import the certificate to the cloud service. and also import the
   certificate to local machine personal store.
3. add certificate configuration for the web role in the visual studio
   2010.
4. publish the project to cloud services.

and It works fine. 
But when I tried to import `RemoteAccess` and `RemoteForwarder` modules to the configuration. 
and use the same certificate for the `SSL` and `RemoteAccess`.

the publish action will fail with the error:
`the remote desktop certificate with thumbprint xxxxx does not have a type of key exchange and can not be used for decryption`.

When I remove the `RemoteAccess`. Everything will be fine.

Did anyone ever encounter this issue before ? I didn't know if it is allowed for the cloud service . I mean using the same certificate for the `SSL` and `RemoteAccess`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you don't have key exchange property for your certificate, instead of using the same certificate for SSL and remote. Maybe you can add `-sky exchange` parameter for `makecert.exe` and try again.

Comment: Thanks your reply, :)  In SO , I didn't met Chinese guys before. I am in shenzhen. Where are you now ? thanks.

Comment: I'm in Beijing. Hopefully my reply helps you :)

Comment: So what you mean is I can use the same one with SSL cert, But need generate the cert with the key exchange property to be provided . right ?

Comment: Yes that's what's I suggested.